# How to make Plt.plot show my parabolic line in python?

Tags: python, plot

Maybe this will be duplicate question but I couldn't find any solution for this.
Normally what I coded should show me a curved line in python. But with this code I cant see it. Is there a problem with my code or pycharm ? This code only shows me an empty graphic with the correct axes.

And I did adding "ro" in plt.plot(at[i], st, "ro"). This showed me the spots on the graph but what I want to see the complete line.

```
at = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

for i in range(len(at)):
    st = at[i]**2
    plt.plot(at[i], st)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would normally do this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
at = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])
at2 = at ** 2
plt.plot(at,at2)
plt.show()
```

you can use something like  `plt.plot(at,at2, c='red', marker='o')` to see the spots.

for detailed explanation please read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe rather calculate the to be plotted values entirely before plotting.

```
at = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [xi**2 for xi in at]

plt.plot(at, y)
```

Or do it alternatively with a function

```
from math import pow

at = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]

def parabolic(x):
    return [pow(xi,2) for xi in x]

plt.plot(at, parabolic(at))
```

both return the following plot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

the other answers give fixes for your question, but don't tell you why your code is not working.

the reason for not "seeing anything" is that `plt.plot(at[i], st)` was trying to draw lines between the points you give it.  but because you were only ever giving it single values it didn't have anything to draw lines between.  as a result, nothing appeared on the plot

when you changed to call `plt.plot(at[i], st, 'ro')` you're telling it to draw single circles at points and these don't go between points so would appear

the other answers showed you how to pass multiple values to `plot` and hence matplotlib could draw lines between these values.

one of your comments says "its not parabolic still" and this is because matplotlib isn't a symbolic plotting library.  you just give it numeric values and it draws these onto the output device.  `sympy` is a library for doing symbolic computation and supports plotting, e.g:

```
from sympy import symbols, plot

x = symbols('x')

plot(x**2, (x, 0, 6))
```

does the right thing for me.  the current release (1.4) doesn't handle discontinuities, but this will be [fixed](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/17460) in the next release